# Changed include path behaviour from CMake 2.8.x to 3.9.x

Tags: cmake, include

I have a fairly large cmake project that exhibits a compiler error when I use Makefiles generated by CMake 3.9.x:

```
Scanning dependencies of target client
[ 21%] Building C object 
src/lib/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.c.o
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:40:1: fatal error: compiler.h: No such file or directory
 #endif
 ^
```

This works properly when using Makefiles generated by CMake 2.8.x. Digging in a bit, I can see that a change was made to the **flags.make** file generated by CMake between these two versions. The older version used to put `-I` (include) options in the `C_FLAGS` variable defined in that file:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8
# compile C with /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
C_FLAGS =  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wformat=2 -Wundef -mcx16 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-unused-parameter -D_GNU_SOURCE -include compiler.h -D__BUG_OUT_AUX=pd_trc_ftl -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-tautological-compare -g -I/.../src/lib/client ... -fPIC
C_DEFINES = -DBUILD_NUMBER=\"whatever\" -DBUILD_VERSION=\"1.66.0\" -DCOMMIT_HASH=\"f9bf1c93682f\" -DPDDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

In later versions of CMake the `-I` options are broken out into their own `C_INCLUDES` variable:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.9
# compile C with /usr/lib64/ccache/cc
C_FLAGS =  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wformat=2 -Wundef -mcx16 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-unused-parameter -D_GNU_SOURCE -include compiler.h -D__BUG_OUT_AUX=pd_trc_ftl -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-tautological-compare -g   -fPIC
C_DEFINES = -DBUILD_NUMBER=\"whatever\" -DBUILD_VERSION=\"1.66.0\" -DCOMMIT_HASH=\"f9bf1c93682f\" -DPDDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
C_INCLUDES = -I/.../src/lib/client ...
```

However, in both cases, the including file - **build.make** - uses only the `$(C_DEFINES) $(C_FLAGS)`, omitting the `$(C_INCLUDES)` in the newer model:

```
...
# Include the compile flags for this target's objects.
include src/lib/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/flags.make

src/lib/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.c.o: src/lib/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/flags.make
src/lib/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.c.o: ../src/lib/client/client.c
        @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --progress-dir=/.../cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1) "Building C object src/lib/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.c.o"
        cd /.../cmake-build-debug/src/lib/client && /.../contrib/cc/cgcc.sh /.../cmake-build-debug /usr/lib64/ccache/cc sparse ON /.../client-project CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.c.o $(C_DEFINES) $(C_FLAGS) -o CMakeFiles/client.dir/client.c.o   -c /.../src/lib/client/client.c
...
```

Is this a bug in CMake 3.9.x? Has anyone else experienced anything like this when upgrading CMake?

I believe it's possible that we've always done something wrong in our CMakeLists.txt files that just happened to work in the older versions, but that when we upgraded to CMake 3.9.x, suddenly the problem is manifest. Hoping someone has had this issue and figured out what they did wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a little reason to check Makefiles generated by CMake.You may assume that `CMakeLists.txt` by itself should work according to rules of CMake. If it is not - then there is a bug in CMake. But for fill bugreport you need to have `CMakeLists.txt` which reproduces the problem.

Comment: I suspect response file generation as the root cause: try adding a `set(CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES 0)`.

Comment: Oh and I've seen you are using `ccache`. So how is `ccache` setup in your CMake code? Can you please add that part to your question? Newer versions of CMake recommend using [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html#variable:CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER) (CMake version >= 3.4).